# Read csv file using flink job

Tags: java, apache-kafka, streaming, apache-flink

I have a requirement to read a csv file from a location and convert that into Avro schema and put that onto Kafka topic.
So here there are 3 things.
1)Read a csv file from a specific location using Flink Pipeline
2)Convert the into AVRO schema
3)Put that onto Kafka topic.

Can you provid me any reference for reading a csv file from a specific location.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you simply google "flink read csv" you'll get a good idea of how to do this.

Comment: I had tried few solutions from google but that did not worked here.
Let me know if you have anything in mind.

Comment: Can anyone help me with good source of file reading through Flink